Is it possible to create a PBR cell shader in post-processing
I have been interested in cell shading recently and specifically trying to find something a little more in depth than the 5 minute youtube videos which just add a color ramp and call it a day.
I was blown away by this video: https://youtu.be/eBS3BOI5KnM (which i highly recommend). The only issue being that the project is created in the unreal engine, and I haven't had any luck trying to recycle the concepts in blender.
The advantages seem overwhelming: out of the box functionality to cell shade imported materials, support for colored light and bounce light without complicated work-arounds,  support for shading some textured materials, and high editability which carries over to the entire scene, instead of just one material.
I started researching similar approaches in blender and was surprised to find nothing on youtube or any forums.
Is this something that is possible in blender? are there other approaches that yield similar results? I'm trying to figure out if there are so many youtube videos on the basic color ramp material because it truly is the best method, or just because its the simplest method.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

If you showed us some of your attempts to recreate it and why you believe they went wrong then we should be able to show you how to fix it if it is possible. Looking at that video it doesn't look extremely different than what you would do in Blender, aside from some minor node/render pass naming differences.
